# chart.js in meteor not drawing

Tags: javascript, meteor

In a meteor project, I have copied the demo code from [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) into my client folder as follows:

```
function drawChart(){
  var data = {
  labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
  datasets : [
    {
        fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
        data : [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
    },
    {
        fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
        strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
        data : [28,48,40,19,96,27,100]
    }
    ]
  }

  //Get context with jQuery - using jQuery's .get() method.
  var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
  //This will get the first returned node in the jQuery collection.
  var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx);

  new Chart(ctx).Line(data);
}

Meteor.startup(function() {

  drawChart();

});
```

In the HTML I have:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Nothing is drawn, nor any errors thrown. The same code run in the console produces a chart. What am I missing?

I am using the [meteor-chartjs](https://github.com/donskifarrell/meteor-chartjs) library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the canvas to a template

```
<template name="chart">
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</template>
```

Use the template rendered callback to call your drawChart function

```
Template.chart.rendered = function(){
  drawChart();
}
```

Comment: Could someone explain why does do we need to do it this way? @landland

Comment: You need to put canvas into a template so canvas is rendered. Then you need to tell the template to call the drawChart function to actually draw the chart into canvas, and you do this in the template's rendered callback (rendered into the DOM, so that canvas is now available in the template).

Answer (score 0):

```
function drawChart(){
  var data = {
  labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
  datasets : [
    {
        fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
        data : [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
    },
    {
        fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
        strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
        data : [28,48,40,19,96,27,100]
    }
    ]
  }

  //Get context with jQuery - using jQuery's .get() method.
  //var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
  //This will get the first returned node in the jQuery collection.
  //var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx);

  //new Chart(ctx).Line(data);
  //modify this
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
  var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).PolarArea(data); 
}

Meteor.startup(function() {

  drawChart();

});
```